# How do I check if LWC component has a public method

Tags: lightning-web-components, parent-to-child, querylocator

I have a form with inputs being either standard LWC inputs or custom lookups.
I want to validate the form and report error back to the user.
I use `this.template.querySelector` to get the inputs and want to call `setCustomValidity` on the standard inputs, and a different method on the custom lookups.

How can I test if the proxy returned from querySelector has the `setCustomValidity` method? `hasOwnProperty` does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below approach using JS [typeof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) operator will determine if `setCustomValidity` exists on the DOM element.

```
const inputArray = this.template.querySelectorAll(".inp-cls");

inputArray.forEach(inp => {
    if (typeof inp.setCustomValidity === "function") {
        console.log("setCustomValidity present");
    } else {// We can check any other function as well
        console.log("call custom function");
    }
});
```

Here , we just query the input elements by css selector and check if `setCustomValidity` function exists.